# Запрос по таблице в базе данных MySQL

Tags: sql, запрос, select, table

Добрый вечер.
Есть табличка в базе, например, такая.
[image: 1]

Нужно сделать запрос по ней, чтобы на выходе была уникальная дата в заданном промежутке, посчиталось одно из делений двух колонок, и также была проведена сортировка по четвертой колонке:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date1.table) as d, COUNT(status2)/COUNT(status1)*100
FROM t1.table
WHERE status3 like "eco"
AND date1.table BETWEEN '11-12-2017' and '14-12-2017'
GROUP BY d
```

Чтобы вышел в итоге такой результат:

[image: 2]

Comment: А что это за задача? Тест какой что ли? А то приведенный в вопросе SQL запрос наводит тоску...

Comment: Та у самого наводит тоску, так как не те данные показывает в итоге, которые нужны( мне бы помощь советом пригодилась бы

Comment: ну как бы вообще сомнительно что запрос рабочий

Comment: Можете помочь с запросом, чтобы в итоге вывел по таким критериям похожую табличку?

Comment: Если бы запрос был хотя бы правильным - то можно было бы и чем-то помочь. А делать чужую работу желания нет.

Comment: И чем он не правильный?ошибку по крайней мере не выдает. Ну ладно, и на том спасибо)

Comment: В GROUP BY нельзя указывать поле выходного набора. Замените имя поля на вычисляющее его выражение - `GROUP BY DATE(date1.table)`. И уберите `DISTINCT` - при наличии группировки он смотрится несколько [censored].

Comment: А как сделать тогда, чтобы оно выдало для каждой даты свои деления, а не общаковые значения?

Answer (score 0):

```
    select date1, 
    sum(case when coalesce(status2,'No') = 'Ok' then 1 else 0 end) / 
    sum(case when coalesce(status1, 'No') = 'Ok' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 as nqty
    from t1
    where status3 = 'eco'
    group by date1
```